# How to convert this SQL statement to LINQ?

Tags: sql, linq

I have no idea how to convert this SQL statement to LINQ that uses OUTER APPLY and TOP.  Can somebody give an idea how deal with it.  Thanks!

```
SELECT  Cust.CustomerName, Ord.OnlineOrderTitle, Pro.ProductTitle, 
Pic.PictureFilename, PCom.PictureCommentText, Ord.OnlineOrderDateAdded
FROM Customer as Cust
OUTER APPLY 
(SELECT * FROM OnlineOrder
WHERE CustomerID = Cust.CustomerID) as Ord
OUTER APPLY 
(SELECT * FROM Product
WHERE OnlineOrderID = Ord.OnlineOrderID) as Pro
OUTER APPLY 
(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Accessory 
WHERE ProductID = Pro.ProductID) as Acc
OUTER APPLY 
(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Picture 
WHERE ProductID = Pro.ProductID) as Pic
OUTER APPLY 
(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM PictureComment
WHERE PictureID = Pic.PictureID) as PCom
ORDER BY Ord.OnlineOrderDateAdded DESC
```

Comment: Why not make this a SQL view and use it that way?
Maybve not quite what you want but it definitely one work around.

Comment: This looks a bit like an over-engineered `join`. Perhaps you can re-write it as a `join` in T-SQL, and then convert that to LINQ-to-SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ does not support SQL-style outer joins natively (in the sense of horizontal addition of resultsets), but you can simulate them very easily by doing a grouped join and returning an empty group if the join finds no results. Have a look at the MSDN pages [How to: Perform Left Outer Joins (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx) and [How to: Combine Data with LINQ by Using Joins (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb918093.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for those links.  Very helpful.